# How to handle multiple transaction when transaction instruction is too long

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, send-transaction, sendandconfirmrawtransaction

I have to send multiple transaction at once but if I will add the transaction like...

txn.add([ixn1, ixn2, ixn]);
or txn.add(ixn1);txn.add(ixn2)...

So, this will handle by the solana runtime right, but there is the [limit of 1232 bytes](https://solana.com/docs/programs/deploying) of transaction to append like this.
So, I have to send multiple transaction with the transaction size more than 1232 bytes, So if I will add the transaction like this.....

txList.push(new Transaction().add(tx1Instruction));
txList.push(new Transaction().add(tx2Instruction))....

In this case, solana runtime will not handle transactions, So, How can I handle that multiple transactions which are more than txn limit size because it can be possible one transaction got error and other got succeed, how can I check if one got error and other should not be executed ?

Comment: Depends on your program design. You may need to implement workflow in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Send and confirm the transactions in order. If there is an error sending one of the transactions, an exception will be thrown.

```
try {
  for (const tx of txList) {
    const txSig = await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize(), {
      preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',
    })
    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()
    await connection.confirmTransaction(
      {
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: txSig,
      },
      'confirmed',
    )
  }
} catch (error: any) {
  console.log('Error sending transactions', error)
}
```